# Create a cron job for a python file to run on second day each month

Tags: python, linux, cron

Hello I need to create a cron job for my python script to run on the second day on each month. What is the command line that I need in order to do it?

Comment: What research have you done to try and find the answer on your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All cron tab jobs can be easily created using the command

```
crontab -e
```

Then you should input the text you need to schedule. A good way to do this is using the website crontab.guru
In your case, the configuration once you enter at the edition mode with the command above would be something like

```
0 13 2 * *
```

This means, run at 1 pm on day-of-month 2

More info: https://crontab.guru/#0_13_2_*_*